# Subfigures with captions for thesis using \subfigure package

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats, labels, subcaption

I want to put two figures side by side with their sub captions for my thesis.
The template has the package \subfigure included, thus I cannot use for example \subcaption.
If I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{article}  
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,amssymb,braket,xcolor,subfigure,upgreek,bbold}

\usepackage{esint}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
 \begin{subfigure}[Fig.A]
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=3cm]{Ex_Im.pdf}
     \label{fig:Ex_Im}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[Fig.B]
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=6cm]{Ex_Im2.pdf}
     \label{fig:Ex_Im2}
 \end{subfigure}
\caption{This is the caption.}\label{fig:Label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the following figure:

[image]

If, on the contrary I use:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
 \begin{subfigure}[Fig.A]
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=3cm]{Ex_Im.pdf}
     \label{fig:Ex_Im}
     \caption{This is the caption A.}
 \end{subfigure}
 \begin{subfigure}[Fig.B]
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=6cm]{Ex_Im2.pdf}
     \label{fig:Ex_Im2}
     \caption{This is the caption B.}
 \end{subfigure}
\caption{This is the caption.}\label{fig:Label}
\end{figure}
```

Then I get this:

[image]

So as you can there is no good result with either of those examples.

Thanks in advance for your help.

This is the cls file:

```
%%Thesis.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Thesis}
              [2007/22/02 v1.0
   LaTeX document class]
\def\baseclass{book}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{\baseclass}}
\def\@checkoptions#1#2{
  \edef\@curroptions{\@ptionlist{\@currname.\@currext}}
  \@tempswafalse
  \@tfor\@this:=#2\do{
    \@expandtwoargs\in@{,\@this,}{,\@curroptions,}
    \ifin@ \@tempswatrue \@break@tfor \fi}
  \let\@this\@empty
  \if@tempswa \else \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{\baseclass}\fi
}
\@checkoptions{11pt}{{10pt}{11pt}{12pt}}
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{\baseclass}
\newcommand\bhrule{\typeout{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}}

\newcommand\Declaration[1]{
\btypeout{Declaration of Authorship}
%\addtotoc{Declaration of Authorship}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
%\vskip 60\p@
%\begin{center}{\huge\bf Declaration of Authorship\par}\end{center}
%\vskip 60\p@
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null
%\cleardoublepage
}

\newcommand\btypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space \number\year}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2.0ex plus0.5ex minus0.2ex}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb           { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\topskip}{1\topskip \@plus 5\p@}
\doublehyphendemerits=10000       % No consecutive line hyphens.
\brokenpenalty=10000              % No broken words across columns/pages.
\widowpenalty=9999                % Almost no widows at bottom of page.
\clubpenalty=9999                 % Almost no orphans at top of page.
\interfootnotelinepenalty=9999    % Almost never break footnotes.
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd,amsthm,xspace}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\usepackage[normal,small,sc]{caption}
\setlength{\captionmargin}{20pt}
\newcommand{\fref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eref}[1]{Equation~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\cref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\aref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.85}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.75}
\setcounter{topnumber}{9}
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{9}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{20}
\setcounter{dbltopnumber}{9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstpatch}
\lstset{captionpos=b,
        frame=tb,
        basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
        showstringspaces=false,
        keepspaces=true}
\lstdefinestyle{matlab} {
        language=Matlab,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue},
        commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.13,0.55,0.13}\em,
        stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.7,0,0} }
\usepackage[pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
   bookmarksopenlevel=0,bookmarksnumbered=true,hypertexnames=false,
   colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={red},
   pdfstartview={FitV},unicode,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
   \let\\\space
}
\newcommand*{\supervisor}[1]{\def\supname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\examiner}[1]{\def\examname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\degree}[1]{\def\degreename{#1}}
\newcommand*{\authors}[1]{\def\authornames{#1}}
\newcommand*{\addresses}[1]{\def\addressnames{#1}}
\newcommand*{\university}[1]{\def\univname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\UNIVERSITY}[1]{\def\UNIVNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\department}[1]{\def\deptname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\DEPARTMENT}[1]{\def\DEPTNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\group}[1]{\def\groupname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\GROUP}[1]{\def\GROUPNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\faculty}[1]{\def\facname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\FACULTY}[1]{\def\FACNAME{#1}}
\newcommand*{\subject}[1]{\def\subjectname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\keywords}[1]{\def\keywordnames{#1}}
\supervisor  {}
\examiner    {}
\degree      {}
\authors     {}
\university  {\texorpdfstring{\href{University Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {University Name}}
                {University Name}}
\UNIVERSITY  {\texorpdfstring{\href{University Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {}
                {UNIVERSITY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
\department  {\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {}}
                {Department or School Name}}
\DEPARTMENT  {\texorpdfstring{\href{Department or School Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
                {DEPARTMENT OR SCHOOL NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
\group       {\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {Research Group Name}}
                {Research Group Name}}
\GROUP       {\texorpdfstring{\href{Research Group Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
                {RESEARCH GROUP NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
\faculty     {\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {Faculty Name}}
                {Faculty Name}}
\FACULTY     {\texorpdfstring{\href{Faculty Web Site URL Here (include http://)}
                {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
                {FACULTY NAME (IN BLOCK CAPITALS)}}
\addresses   {}
\subject     {}
\keywords    {}
\renewcommand\maketitle{
  \btypeout{Title Page}
  \hypersetup{pdftitle={\@title}}
  \hypersetup{pdfsubject=\subjectname}
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authornames}
  \hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \let\footnotesize\small
    \let\footnoterule\relax
    \let \footnote \thanks
    \setcounter{footnote}{0}
    \null\vfil
    \vskip 60\p@
    \begin{center}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      %{\large\textbf{\UNIVNAME}\par}
      %\vfill
      {\huge \bf \@title \par}
      \vfill
      %{\LARGE by \par}
      %\smallskip

      {\large \textbf{\authornames} \par}
      \vfill
      {\large A thesis submitted for the degree of\par}
      {\large \textbf{Doctor of Philosophy} \par}
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      %{\large in the \par}
      %{\large \facname \par}
      {\large \textbf{\deptname} \par}
      {\large\textbf{\UNIVNAME}\par}
      \bigskip
      \bigskip
      {\large \textbf{\authornames} \par}
      \vfill
      \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{} 
        \bigskip
      \bigskip
      \bigskip

        \ \
      {\large \@date \par}
      \bigskip
    \end{center}
    \par
    \@thanks
    \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
  \cleardoublepage
}
\newenvironment{abstract}
{
 \btypeout{Abstract Page}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
   {\huge \textbf{Abstract} \par}
    \bigskip
}
{
  \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
  \cleardoublepage
}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\newcounter{dummy}
\newcommand\addtotoc[1]{
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
\btypeout{Table of Contents}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}
    \@starttoc{toc}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
   \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoffigures{
\btypeout{List of Figures}
%\addtotoc{List of Figures}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}}
    \@starttoc{lof}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\renewcommand\listoftables{
\btypeout{List of Tables}
%\addtotoc{List of Tables}
\begin{spacing}{1}{
    \setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listtablename
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listtablename}{\MakeUppercase\listtablename}}
    \@starttoc{lot}
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \cleardoublepage
}\end{spacing}
}
\newcommand\listsymbolname{Abbreviations}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofsymbols[2]{
\btypeout{\listsymbolname}
\addtotoc{\listsymbolname}
    \chapter*{\listsymbolname
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}{\MakeUppercase\listsymbolname}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listconstants{Physical Constants}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofconstants[2]{
\btypeout{\listconstants}
\addtotoc{\listconstants}
    \chapter*{\listconstants
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listconstants}{\MakeUppercase\listconstants}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\listnomenclature{Symbols}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand\listofnomenclature[2]{
\btypeout{\listnomenclature}
\addtotoc{\listnomenclature}
    \chapter*{\listnomenclature
      \@mkboth{
          \MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}{\MakeUppercase\listnomenclature}}
\begin{longtable}[c]{#1}#2\end{longtable}\par
    \cleardoublepage
}
\newcommand\acknowledgements[1]{
\btypeout{Acknowledgements}
%\addtotoc{Acknowledgements}
\thispagestyle{plain}
{\huge{\textbf{Acknowledgements}} \par}
\bigskip
{\normalsize #1}
\vfil\vfil\null

}
\newcommand\dedicatory[1]{
\btypeout{Dedicatory}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\null\vfil
\vskip 60\p@
\begin{center}{\Large \sl #1}\end{center}
\vfil\null
\cleardoublepage
}
\renewcommand\backmatter{
  \if@openright
    \cleardoublepage
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \addtotoc{\bibname}
  \btypeout{\bibname}
  \@mainmatterfalse}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `Thesis.cls'.
```

Comment: Done. Regarding the \subfigure, even if I don't include it in the \usepackage it tells me it is still there.

Comment: The syntax is completely wrong: with the `subfigure` package, there is a `\subfigure` command, not a `subfigure` environment.

Answer (score 1):

The `subfigure` package provides a `\subfigure` command, not an environment.

The syntax is

```
\subfigure[<optional argument>]{mandatory argument}
```

what happens with your code is that the mandatory argument is `\centering`. Chaos ensues.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,amssymb,braket,xcolor,subfigure,upgreek,bbold}

\usepackage{esint}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfigure[Fig.\ A]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}\label{fig:Ex_Im}}
\subfigure[Fig.\ B]{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}\label{fig:Ex_Im2}}

\caption{This is the caption.}\label{fig:Label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, `subfigure` is obsolete and you should prefer either `subfig` or `subcaption`.

With the former package, the syntax is

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,amssymb,braket,xcolor,subfig,upgreek,bbold}

\usepackage{esint}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\subfloat[Fig.\ A]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}\label{fig:Ex_Im}}\quad
\subfloat[Fig.\ B]{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}\label{fig:Ex_Im2}}

\caption{This is the caption.}\label{fig:Label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With the latter, you can use `\subcaptionbox`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{report}  
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,amssymb,braket,xcolor,subcaption,upgreek,bbold}

\usepackage{esint}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\subcaptionbox{Fig.\ A\label{fig:Ex_Im}}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}\quad
\subcaptionbox{Fig.\ B\label{fig:Ex_Im2}}{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}}

\caption{This is the caption.}\label{fig:Label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer `subcaption`, but the class you're using might not like it; in this case, go with `subfig`.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: One small thing though. My (a) and (b) appear as (A) and (B). Any idea why that might occur?

Comment: @Kio No, if you don't point to a place where the `Thesis` class can be examined.

Comment: But I need to use this Thesis template...

Comment: @Kio Sure, but if I can't see it, there's nothing I can say about the labels.

Comment: Could it be something I can change in the cls file?

Comment: @Kio Last time I ask: can you make the document class available? Without knowing its internals it's *impossible* to help. There are literally hundreds of `Thesis` classes around.

Comment: I have added it now.

Comment: @Kio As far as I can see, your class already loads `subfigure`, so you have to resort to the first code I wrote (with the `\subfigure` command). I get (a) and (b) (lowercase).

Comment: If I do that the figures appears on top of each other and not subcaption. I commented the \subfigure in the cls file and then I can use \subcaption, but (a) and (b) appear in capital letters then.