# Section in header not shown

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, thesis

I am trying to display the name of the section as the header on each page of my thesis.

I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
```

but still the chapter's name shows instead of the section.

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which document class do you employ?

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}

Comment: There are lots and lots of LaTeX document class files called `Thesis.cls` out there on the Internet. Which one might you be using? Is the file available online?

Comment: It's the cls file I included here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519518/subfigures-with-captions-for-thesis-using-subfigure-package

Comment: In the linked Thesis.class, \sectionmark doesn't do anything..  Normally it calls \markright or \markboth.  If you are supposed to use this class, I wouldn't mess with it.